# I can't refresh my ArrayAdaper listview :S ¿how to do it?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

i searched on stackoverflow for how to refres a listview that uses ArrayAdapter, and i find some solutions, but any of these solutions didn't work for me!

i have a interface with a NumberPicker, and a listview. When i press on the buttons of the numberpickers, the listview must update itself, but didn't works. When i press the buttons the listview didn't update itselft, it stay with the same data... but it have to update because when you press a button, you are changing one parameter of the adapter and the adapter is receiving new data...

this is my code:

```
public class Calendar extends Activity {
    private ListView CalendarList = null;
    private NumberPicker CalendarPicker = null;
    private ArrayAdapter MyArrayAdapter = null;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calendar);

        CalendarList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.CalendarList);
        CalendarPicker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.CalendarPicker);

        CalendarPicker.setMaxValue(((MyApplication.NEQUIPOS*2)-2));//el maximo valor alcanzable por el picker es el numero de jornadas de la liga, es decir, ((NEQUIPOS*2)-2)
        CalendarList.setClickable(false);
        CalendarList.setFocusable(false);
        CalendarList.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        CalendarList.setSelected(false);
        CalendarList.setEnabled(false);

        CalendarPicker.increment.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CalendarPicker.increment();     
                MyArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

    }

    public void onResume() {
         super.onResume();
        CalendarPicker.setValue(MyApplication.RoundNumber);
        MyArrayAdapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, MyApplication.roundMatches(CalendarPicker.getValue()));
        MyArrayAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);

        CalendarList.setAdapter(MyArrayAdapter);
      }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you call `MyArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` feed the adapter with the new data and then call `MyArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`